# overloading + operator to add a const char

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have a struct :

```
struct t { 
 string data;
 t(string new_data) { data = new_data; }
 string operator +(const char *operand) { return data + string(operand); }
}
```

when I write

```
t y="text"; 
string x = "\r\n" + t;
```

it (ms visual 2015) says "no operator "+" matches these operands" and the mouse over hint of the "+" source in the editor says "operand types are const char [3] + text" which suggest my overloaded operator should work, doesn't it?
What do I have to do so that I can add type t strings to const chars like that?

Answer (score 4):

Member function binary operator overloads are only invoked when the class is on the *left* side of the operator. If you need to handle the case where your class is on the right hand side of the operator with a built-in (that doesn't recognize how to work with your class) on the left, you need a non-member overload, e.g. (defined outside the class):

```
// No need to explicitly stringify operand, since string already overloads
// + for const char*
string operator+(const char *left, const t& right) { return left + right.data; }
```

Which would make `string x = "\r\n" + t;` set `x` to `"\r\ntest"s`.

I'd strongly recommend reading [the operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/364696) now, before you write yourself into a corner here; one of the first things you learn is not to implement `operator+` as a member function (only `+=` would be a member).

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you meant to use

```
string x = "\r\n" + y; // y is the object, t is the type.
```

and not

```
string x = "\r\n" + t;
```

When you define `operator+` as a member function, the first argument has to be an object of the class.

You need to use:

```
string x = y + "\r\n";
```

If you want to be able use

```
string x1 = y + "\r\n";
string x2 = "\r\n" + y;
```

you need a non-member function that supports the second form.

```
string operator+(const char* operand, t const& y);
```

To be symmetric, you should support both of them as non-member functions.

```
string operator+(t const& y, const char* operand);
string operator+(const char* operand, t const& y);
```

and implement one in terms of the other.

```
string operator+(t const& y, const char* operand)
{
   return (y.data + string(operand));
}

string operator+(const char* operand, t const& y)
{
   return (y + operand);
}
```

Comment: But that will yield "text\r\n" ! How do I get "\r\ntext" ?

Comment: @user3100031 You can't use the member function for this. You need to define an overloaded operator outside the class, and make it a friend.

Comment: Actually, since your members are public, it doesn't need to be a friend.